# Crear tareas programadas en JS o PHP

Tags: javascript, php

La pregunta es, ¿Cómo logro que se genere una nueva factura el mes siguiente, sin que nadie abra mi sitio web?, tengo entendido que JavaScript necesita ser ejecutado, por ende no hay Ajax, sin Ajax no funciona php ¿o si?, esa es otra duda, en un hosting, el código backend funciona sin ejecutarse, es decir, el servidor, ¿mantiene ejecutando mis archivos php o de node?. ¡Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: Front -> Cliente: lo que ves en una web y se ejecuta en tu ordenador.
Back -> Servidor: Otra maquina, normalmente 24 horas encendida que recibe y envia peticiones

Comment: Buenos días, gracias por tu pronta respuesta. Pero en el caso de no tener abierta la pagina, no estaría enviando peticiones al backend, mi pregunta es si yo puedo modificar la base de datos, desde el backend, sin enviar una petición.

Comment: Buenas, Kevin, bienvenido al sitio. Como indica Nicolás, el servidor siempre está encendido. Lo que tienes que hacer es crear una tarea programada que se ejecute una vez al mes, un día y una hora determinados, y que genere la facturación. Cómo programar esa tarea depende del sistema operativo y/o del framework concreto que uses.

Comment: @KevinDana si, de hecho es lo mas común.. Por favor edita tu respuesta para que sea mejor recibida, mira por favor [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y te invito a que también hagas el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Para dejar un server de node corriendo permanentemente puedes usar pm2 para controlar los procesos y [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) para ejecutar tareas programadas en el servidor, si editas la pregunta pongo una respuesta completa, un saludo.

Comment: Gracias a todos, me quedo claro. Mis disculpas si hice uso inadecuado de preguntas o respuestas, nunca publique en este foro.

Answer (score 3):

Pues hay diferentes alternativas, al menos para JavaScript te lo puedo asegurar.

Antes de empezar, una breve explicación de lo que es un backend:

Un backend es el código que se está ejecutando en un servidor, naturalmente 24/7, nunca se suelen apagar. Este puede realizar casi todas las tareas repetitivas que puedas imaginar, suelen servir a los frontEnd, pero muchas veces también a otros backends (APIs), y al menos en backends basados en JavaScript (NodeJS), puedes correr otros procesos (p.e: cómo crees que se suele hacer streaming de vídeos?? Una instancia de FFmpeg de fondo convirtiendo los vídeos en segmentos).

Dicho esto, si ya tienes un backend funcionando siempre y tienes la seguridad de que siempre está en marcha, tienes una alternativa.

### Cron

Cron es un administrador de tareas extremadamente potente. Puedes especificar de distintas formas cuando quieres ejecutar determinado proceso.

Una muestra de cómo funciona:

```
┌────────────── Segundo(s) (opcional)
│ ┌──────────── Minuto(s)
│ │ ┌────────── Horas
│ │ │ ┌──────── Dia(s) del mes
│ │ │ │ ┌────── Mes(es)
│ │ │ │ │ ┌──── Día(s) de la semana
│ │ │ │ │ │
│ │ │ │ │ │
* * * * * *
```

La estructura de un trabajo cron tiene la sintaxis de arriba.

Ahora, en tu caso, la definición de tu trabajo sería la siguiente:

```
* * * 1 * *
```

Esto lanzará la tarea el día 1 de cada mes.

Para implementarlo en JS, instala [node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron) y después incluye este código en un archivo que hayas importado/requerido para que el código se ponga en marcha.

```
cron.schedule('* * * 1 * *', () => {
  // Código para generar facturas.
});
```

Si no me he confundido en la sintaxis, esto debería funcionar bien. De todas formas, haz pruebas y revisa que esté bien, no se te ocurra ponerlo en producción sin probar.

Comment: Bueno también tomar en cuenta que una ejecución en servidor para producción no es solo dejar la app de node corriendo, por ejemplo si se reinicia el servidor la app no va a iniciarse, por lo que tienes que registrar un servicio para eso. O simplemente usar pm2 para administrar los procesos y asegurar la ejecución en el arranque.

Comment: Exacto, no lo había tenido en cuenta. Sin embargo en un hosting, la app se vuelve a levantar automáticamente, es decir, heroku vuelve a poner en marcha el servidor si este se ha caído, si no me equivoco, corrígeme si es así

Comment: Heroku es una PaaS lo que quiere decir que es una plataforma lista para hacer deploy de la app o testear, y mas glitch que no solo es PaaS sino que es un sitio colaborativo para testear código. Normalmente cuando lanzas una app que sabes que va a escalar y necesitas controlar bien los recursos, usas un VPS, VPC o baremetal, a de mas es mas barato y tienes control total del sistema operativo.

Comment: Hay muchas cosas que no te dejaria hacer heroku, al menos nativamente un par de ejemplos es que es efimero y la data es inmutable una vez esta deployed. Lo que quiere decir que no puedes escribir archivos en fs. Otro ejemplo es que no podrias correr un binario de FFmpeg :P al menos no sin plugins y cosas asi, que a veces tambien son pagos en heroku.